# iOS video from memory (not from storage or web resource)

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I need to play video from memory (not from storage or web resource).

It's important because I am working on encrypting and need to save files on storage with `DES` encrypt. After decrypting I have `byte[]` and I can get from it any image or sound to be playing... But I don't know how to play video without saving it on storage in encrypted state (it brakes a my work on security)

Does some body know any solution to get `AVAsset` or `URL` on `byte[]`?